# Modular Arithmetic with Sines

Tags: trigonometry, modular-arithmetic

Given $$\sin(10^{100})+\sin(n)=0$$ find $n$.

I wrote so far that $$\sin(10^{100})=\sin(10^{100} \mod 360)$$ and I noticed that $10^3 \mod 360=280$ and $10^4 \mod 360=280$ so I (correctly) assumed that $$10^{100} \mod 360=280$$

but why is this the case?

Comment: Please clarify which restrictions you want on $n$ and whether you are working with radians or degrees.

Answer (score 1):

And regarding your problem, considering $n$ in degrees, you want to know why we have,

$$10^{100}\equiv 280\pmod{360}$$

Right? Well, you can simply verify the result using [Euler's Totient Theorem](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem).

$$\phi(360)=\phi(3^2\times 2^3\times 5)=360\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)=96$$

where $\phi(n)$ is the [Euler Totient function](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function) that counts the totatives of $n$.

Now, what the theorem tells us is,

$$10^{96}\equiv 1\pmod{360}\implies 10^{100}\equiv 10^4\pmod{360}$$

$10^4=1000\times 10\equiv (-80)\times 100\equiv (-8)\times 1000\equiv (-8)\times (-80)\equiv 640\equiv 280\pmod{360}$

Hence, we have,

$$\boxed{10^{100}\equiv 280\pmod{360}}$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with that theorem, could you explain it?

Comment: @user228084, I have added the links in the answer. Check those out.

Comment: @user228084, Are you familiar with Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: no i am not familiar w that

Comment: @user228084, According to Euler's theorem, if $a,n\in\Bbb{Z^+}$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then the following congruence holds: $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$

Comment: And Fermat's Little Theorem is the special case of Euler's Theorem when $n$ is prime.

Comment: Or you could use $ \sin(A) + \sin(B) = 2 \sin \left [ \frac {(A+B}{2} \right ] \cos \left [ \frac {(A-B}{2} \right ] $

Answer (score 0):

It seems your argument is in degrees, as you are worried with residue modulo 360, so I will make this assumption. Modular rings work like a cartesian product of the modulos of the prime factor powers. So, $\mathbb{Z}_{360}$ behaves exactly like $\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_9\times\mathbb{Z}_5$. Writing 10 in the latter ring, we have $2\times 1\times 0$. Then cube that to get $10^3$: $0\times 1\times 0$. Multiplying this (component-wise) by 10 ($2\times 1\times 0$) does not change it. So, any power of 10 three and above is equal to any other.